# Query on MVVM design pattern on WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am using MVVM architecture.

I have a usercontrol **UC** as a **View**

**Model** is a **ModelData** class

**ViewModel** (**UCViewModel**) is binded to a usercontrol.

I have three more usercontrols that is inside the usercontrol **UC**  ( discussed above).

Let's say uc1, uc2 and uc3.

and the visibility of uc1 , uc2 and uc3 inside **UC** depends on the type selected ( which ever radio button is selected ).

Since UC is binded to UCViewModel and I have to do all the stuff related to uc1 , uc2 and uc3 inside UCViewModel. Can I have seperate VM to uc1 , uc2 and uc3.. if Yes how can i do that ? Please Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you can solve this by having `UC` expose a `SelectedSubView` (or whatever) property:

```
public object SelectedSubView { get; }
```

At the same time, you bind the radiobuttons to other properties of `UC` and update `SelectedSubView` accordingly (remember to implement INotifyPropertyChanged). Based on the selected radiobutton properties, the `SelectedSubView` must return the appropriate ViewModel.

You then bind a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) to the `SelectedSubView` property and use **DataTemplates** to select the correct user controls (uc1, uc2 or uc3) based on the type of the current `SelectedSubView`.

---

Since you only want to hide inactive Views, it's probably best to keep their respective ViewModels around, so you may want to make them fields in the `UC` class

```
public class UC
{
    private MyFirstViewModel vm1;
    private MySecondViewModel vm2;
    private MyThirdViewModel vm3;
    private object selectedVM;

    public object SelectedSubView
    {
        get { return this.selectedVM; }
    }

    // This method should be called whenever one of the radio buttons
    // are updated (from their bindings)
    private void UpdateSelectedView()
    {
        this.selectedVM = // pick from vm1, vm2, vm3 according to radio button

        // Remember to raise INotifyPropertyChanged for SelectedSubView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply.. Can you please give me an idea of returing a viewmodel or how to set the viewmodel at runtime?

Comment: @Ashish Ashu: Updated my answer.