# How do I inject dependencies to user controls in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

What is the best way to transparently inject dependencies (using IOC container) to user controls in WPF?

I assume that user controls are part of XAML for the window or other user controls.
Also I think parent (whoever it is) should not be responsible for this. Solution for manually injecting dependencies from parent looks not clean enough for me. I want to avoid managing the dependencies of my components explicitly as it voilates the idea of IOC.

Is any event which is raised when logical tree is being created so I can intercept it and inject my dependencies?

EDIT:
by dependencies I also mean ViewModel, Controller, Presenter (whatever pattern is used)

Thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One of the possible ways to solve the problem is to go with "ViewModel First" approach and using convention over configuration.

Comment: How does this posting adequately answer the question? What does using viewmodel-first have to do with specifying ctor parameters for User Controls?

Answer (score 10):

The best way to deal with dependencies in WPF is by following the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

In short, you don't inject dependencies directly into User Controls (View), but rather into their [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) (ViewModel).

Comment: Sure, but ViewModel is just example of the dependency

Comment: So how would you inject ViewModel to user control?

Comment: Set the DataContext property.

Comment: From parent control? it means that parent should be able to create ViewModel for user control (either using access to container or abstract factory). Also I don't like the idea of parent taking care of children dependencies - this violate idea of IoC. Anyway this is actually how I do now, but looking for the better ways.

Comment: No, from the parent ViewModel. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400108/query-on-mvvm-design-pattern-on-wpf/2400198#2400198

Comment: ViewModel is an implementation detail of my view and ideally nobody should aware even about its existence (including ViewModel for the control parent). I don't want to worry about initializing control.ViewModel everytime I put control in XAML. Ideally...

Comment: It sounds like you are using MVP and not MVVM. You are perfectly entitled to do that, but that's just not my recommendation...

Comment: I'm not. Also I've never heard that MVVM somehow define the way how you should manager controls hierarchy. Would be interested to read about that.

Comment: @andrey.tsykunov I inject the VM in the View, but I inject the UCView programmatically (not from xaml) from the View, which receives the UCView as injection: ` public MainWindow(IView view)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewTarget.Children.Add((UIElement) view);
        }`

Comment: @andrey.tsykunov I am using ViewModelLocator for that. Use it in XAML and create/resolve VM instances in the ViewModelLocator.

Comment: The way I handle hooking up views with their VMs most of the time is to simply use data templating.  In other words, the actual content of a parent (some kind of content control) would be the VM itself while having a DataTemplate defined in the resources that hooks the two up, resulting in the VM being the DataContext of the view.
`<DataTemplate TargetType="vm:MyVM"><MyView /></DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 1):

FrameworkElement has an Initialized event, which you could hook up and inject the dependencies. You should test if it comes early enough for your scenario.

Comment: Looks like it happens while view ctor is executed (from InitializeComponent).

_container.Resolve<MainView>()
mainView.Initialized += mainView_Initialized; // never happens
mainView.Show();

Answer (score 1):

The way i did it is to have an overall application class which injects dependencies into your viewmodel class (assuming your using MVVM design pattern ?) - use a DI container like Unity. See the WPF Application Framework (https://github.com/jbe2277/waf) which contains samples of just such a scenario that you're describing.

Comment: Not sure I understand how you access user controls from the application. Anyway this is what I want to avoid - managing dependencies.

Comment: The injection of dependencies can be taken care of by a dependency container like Unity. I don't know your specific case, but it looks like you're not using data binding (to say nothing of MVVM) ? If so, i recommend you investigate these aspects further - a lot of the power of WPF is because of these techniques.

Comment: no, I'm using MVVM, but this does not matter. And the question is of cause about injecting dependencies using IOC container (again does not matter which one).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays with built-in DI support, it's easy to achieve that.

1. Setup service provider in your app:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public partial class App
    {
        private static readonly IHost _host = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c => { c.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location)!); })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                // register your services
                services.AddScoped<ISomething, Something>();
                services.AddScoped<MyUserControlViewModel>();
            })
            .Build();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets registered service.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the service to get.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>Instance of the service or <see langword="null"/>.</returns>
        public static T GetService<T>()
            where T : class
        {
            var service = _host.Services.GetService(typeof(T)) as T;
            return service!;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the application is loading.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            _host.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the application is closing.
        /// </summary>
        private async void OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            await _host.StopAsync();

            _host.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

2. In your user control

Note that you cannot inject the VM to your user control as parameterless contructor will be called when you use the user control in the page, so just get it from service provider

```cs
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControlViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public OrgSwitcherControl()
    {        
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MyUserControlViewModel>();
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

with pages, you can inject the VMs directly (of course you have to register xaml pages in service collection as well).

Answer (score 0):

I Think the only viable solution is to use the "Service Locator Pattern". Your View models are injectable , but the controls/ windows themselves are not. Thus your can use an IOC container to manage the VM's dependencies and have any business logic dependencies (e.g services) injected into your view model

Example

**User Control**

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{

    public MyControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
        Vm = VmLocator.GetVm<MyControlVm >();
       
    }

    public MyControlVm Vm { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyControlVm: VmBase{
    private MyDataService  _service;
    public ICommand DoWork => new ActionCommand(OnDoWork)
    MyControlVm(MyDataService service){
      _service=service;
    }
    private async Task OnDoWork(){
        await _service.DoWorkAsync();
    }
}
```

**Bootstrap**

```
   public  static class Bootstrapper {
       public  statvoid Configure(IServiceCollection collection)
        {
    
            collection     
                .AddTransient<MyDataService >()
                .AddTransient<MyOtherDataService>()
        }
   }
```

With this convention you can have the benefits of DI but there are these caveats.
Unfortunately  I don't think there is a way to control how the Framework Elements themselves are instantiated by the WPF and override that behavior

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this mind block too:

> Also I think parent (whoever it is)
>   should not be responsible for this.

Then who will?  The point of IoC is that something else (parent, view model, something, ...) defines the dependencies.

Comment: old I know, but what he is searching for is a neat solution to *trigger* the injection of those dependencies by the `IoC` Container.