# Setting UserControl ViewModel Property

Tags: wpf, unity-container

All -

I am using Unity in my WPF application for DI (without prism). I have my MainWindow.xaml and MainWindowViewModel.cs. I have a usercontrol in my Mainwindow.xaml. The user control has its own uc1.xaml and uc1viewmodel.cs. The UC1 ViewModel is currently exposed as a property on MainWindowViewModel so I can set the datacontext on the usercontrol (as recommended by many ppl here).

The question I have is how/where can I set this property - will it be in app.xaml.cs or will it be in the constructor of mainwindowviewmodel. Code Snippets:

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //Step 1 - One Time - Creating an instance of the container
        UnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();

        //Step 2 - Registering your MainWindowViewModel
        unity.RegisterType<IViewModel, UserControl1ViewModel>();

        //Step 3 - Creating an Instance
        UserControl1ViewModel uc1_mwvm = unity.Resolve<UserControl1ViewModel>();  <-- doesnt help
        MainWindowViewModel mwvm = unity.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();

        MainWindow mw = unity.Resolve<MainWindow>();

        mw.Show();
    }
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public IViewModel IVM { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //IVM = new UserControl1ViewModel(); <-- All I really want is an equivalent but letting Unity do the work. 
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="_05_ViewFist_UC_Unity_Working.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:uc1="clr-namespace:_05_ViewFist_UC_Unity_Working"
     xmlns:uc2="clr-namespace:_05_ViewFist_UC_Unity_Working"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NNN}" />
    <uc1:UC1 DataContext="{Binding UC1VM}" />
    <uc2:UC2 DataContext="{Binding UC2VM}" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

UC1

```
<UserControl x:Class="_05_ViewFist_UC_Unity_Working.UC1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="UC1 "  />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"  />
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

As you see from the code - Instance of UC1 is created in xaml (MainWindow.xaml) and hence when MainWindow instance is created in app.xaml.cs - it still doesnt create an instance of UserControl1ViewModel.

Question again is : Dont think its a good practice for me to call the Unity Resolve statement in the constructor of MainwindowViewModel. Is that correct??

Can somebody share a code snippet of how/where I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Set the property in constructor of MainWindowViewModel. Don't use App.xaml.cs.

Comment: Ninja - in that case - wouldnt I have to pass an instance of Unity here (or create another instance here). I remember reading somwhere that its a singleton but not sure if this is the right approach. UnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();
IVM = unity.Resolve<UserControl1ViewModel>(); This works though as you are suggesting

Comment: First of all unity is meant to be used for dependency injection. If you dont know what that is stay away from it. Just dont use it and set your properties in constructor. If you still want to use unity then you will have to use attributes like [Dependency] above your properties in your MainWindowViewModel so unity knows how to do the injection.

Comment: Ninja - I very well understand what DI is and Unity being one of the methodologies to achieve it. Agree didnt have the [Dependancy] above my attributes since was trying to keep the code here shorter.

Comment: Well then you propbably know that once you call unity.Resolve(MainWindow) the UnityContainer runs through its register and injects the dependecies you specified in MainWindow. If you have done everything correct in your code that we dont get to see because you wish to keep it here short :) then UnityContainer will set your property after the constructor of MainWindow was called. And you dont need to set anything by yourself. Btw in my example here MainWindow is just an example class.

Comment: Ninja - here is the disconnect. Ideally as you suggest when I resolve MainWindow all internal dependancies should get resolved too - but when using with User Controls it doesnt. Check these forums threads which have the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408873/how-do-i-inject-dependencies-to-user-controls-in-wpf. There are many more. My question was specifically around that - in order for me to set the data context - I need to have an instance of the property set (which doesnt happen by default through mainwindowviewmodel

Comment: I used unity and it did work for me no matter if customcontrol or usercontrol or just simple mainwindow. How about you post us more of your code you didnt want to post in first place because to keep this thread short :) Let us debug your code and then we will be able to solve the problem. To be honest I am still not sure what you exactly mean with mainwindowviewmodel. The name tells me its like a simple viewmodel that you wish to use as datacontext but sometimes you keep mentioning it like its code behind of your mainwindow. Just post more code. Nobody is gonna copy paste it dont worry :) :)

Comment: Ninja - Sorry for the delay. I have modified the code snippet above to be more detailed and also uploaded a working sample solution highlighting the issue here -https://github.com/pratikrshah/SO_Unity_Sample_Issue

Comment: I cant run it. I get an error in my visual studio. :-(

Comment: Ninja - not sure if the reason is - this is compiled in VS 2012 and 4.5 (just happens to be my base environment). Since you have the full sourcecode now - is it possibly you can copy the files into your working environment and try then. Alternatively - I can try to compile this in 4.0 framework too - but we may still hit a similar issue. Let me know. Also will be available in chat 1.5 hrs from now. Appreciate all the help in this

Comment: Ninja - I am online for a chat if you can make it

Comment: I will try your example in few hours when i am home from work :) :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks - will be online for next 6 hrs for fact. Thanks a lot and appreciate the help.

Comment: I tried to run your example on my private computer with vs2010 and vs2012 and still the same error. It seems the solution is broken for whatever reason but I wont let got that easly and I will try few more ticks today to make it run. I will let you know once I solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks Ninja - really appreciate - just a suggestion - since the code runs perfectly on my side - to remove environmental dependencies/issues - if you just copy the code file by file in your dev enviornment - it may be faster....I am assuming the error is with sln file/unity incompatibles. Let me know in any which way i can help to get past this issue. Will gladly do it

Comment: Hey Ninja - were you able to look into this. Just checking in - no pressure. As always - plz let me know how I can help.

Comment: Hi, I am still having isuess getting it to run. The problem are references now. You should create a folder called Lib and copy all the Unity DLL's in there and all Windows.Practies.dlls. I miss them on my computer locally.

Comment: I was using nuget package to get the Unity dlls. I can get them locally referenced and upload a new solution shortly

Comment: Ninja - just updated a new solution here. Its no longer using Nuget and I have locally created a Unitydll folder and copied the dlls there (2 of them as you have stated). So now you will have it locally with the solution. Please download from here -  https://github.com/pratikrshah/SO_Unity_Sample_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your solution from github and tried to solve your problem.

You did a great job just you forgot few details such as property attributes.

This is how your App.cs file shall look alike:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //Step 1 - One Time - Creating an instance of the container
        UnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();

        //Step 2 - Registeration
        unity.RegisterType<IMainWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel>();
        unity.RegisterType<IUC1ViewModel, UC1ViewModel>();
        unity.RegisterType<IUC2ViewModel, UC2ViewModel>();


        //// Instance of MainWindowViewModel will be created once you call Resolve MainWindow.


        MainWindow mw = unity.Resolve<MainWindow>();

        mw.Show();
    }
```

Here is what I changed:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IMainWindowViewModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    [Dependency]
    public IUC1ViewModel UC1VM { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public IUC2ViewModel UC2VM { get; set; }

    public string NNN { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        NNN = "This value coming from MainWindowViewModel";
    }
}
```

`[Dependency]` is a property attibute that tells Unity where to inject values.

I could merge my code to your repo in github if you wish so.

Comment: Ninja/Dev - Thank you so so much for helping me to get this work. Just tried this in my sample solution and works beautifully. This was exactly what I was looking for from an approach perspective. I know you had mentioned [Dependency] attribute previously in your comments but I just didnt get it untill you showed me the above snippet. I really appreciate that you worked though the issues of the download and helped me get here. Have already marked this an answer and given you a upvote :)

Comment: Btw - Is this your enterprise ?? - hhogdev.com Either ways if you can send me your email address - wanted to talk/chat through email a couple of things with regards to DI/WPF - not issues :) My email address is listed through my profile (its public)

Comment: Hi, no that is not my enterprise, hehe. There are few of us calling themselves hedgehog. I have no idea how we came up with that hedgehog thing but there is like ninja hedgegog, me the dev hedgehog, then there is samurai hedgehog and so on. my mail addy is devhedgehog@gmail.com hit me up with whatever wpf issue you have. :)

Comment: Wow - I thought you and ninja were the same :):). Thanks for your email address - will drop you note shortly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service locator pattern. I use it with Unity as a DI.

```
internal class ServiceLocator
{
    [...]
    public MainViewModel Main { get { return container.Resolve<MainViewModel>(); } }
}
```

You can intantiate your class the way you want (DI or not, the class initializes the DI or receive it as a parameter, you can store the DI in a private static property, you can initialize your class if DI is null or when the application starts etc...).

In your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <vm:ServiceLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And now, you can set your datacontext

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Edit:

I found another way of doing it (among other):
Take a look at [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/). In the command, you can resolve your viewmodel as you like.

Comment: Daniel - The issue here is not to instantiate my MainWindowViewModel class but rather my UserControl1ViewModel in my MWVM so I can set up the binding. I believe the solution you are giving is one of the patterns to instantiate MainWindowViewModel class (which I am already doing through Constructor Injection)

Comment: It is exactly the same for your usercontrol. I can rename it if you like

Comment: Thanks - let me try and get back. No need to rename :)

Comment: Looked more at this and see a lot of articles which say dont use Locater Pattern for DI. One prominent article here - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: It is not exactly the same situation. Here, we use Service Locator to resolve our view model only from the view and just once. We don't provide generic method to resolve our class in the code.